# Using strcpy function in C, without knowing the length

Tags: c, string, strcpy

Im trying to write a simple function that get name and return it after adding an extension to it.
for example, if i have the char pointer to "abcd" the function should return "abcd.as"

I tried to write this function that get char pointer and return a pointer to a new char after adding the extension. But is not working does someone know why?

```
char* AddFileExtension(char* FileName)
{
    char* FixFileName=NULL;
    char* Extension = ".as";
    strcpy(FixFileName, FileName);
    strcat(FixFileName, Extension);
    return FixFileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for `FixFileName`:

```
char* Extension = ".as";
char* FixFileName = malloc(strlen(FileName) + strlen(Extension) + 1);
```

Don't forget to `free()` the memory when you're done with it. For obvious reasons, this has to be done outside the function.

Comment: char* FixFileName = malloc(strlen(FileName) + strlen(Extension) + 1); why you added "+1" in the end of malloc?

Comment: @Yuval: For the NUL terminator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Answer (score 1):

you have to allocate memory for `FixFileName` and the size of allocate memory should be the lenght of 
`FileName` + `sizeof(".as")`

**Note:** the `sizeof` will count the null character of `".sa"` string so no need to add 1 for the null charachter of string `FixFileName`

```
char* AddFileExtension(char* FileName)
{
#define EXTENSION_AS ".as"    
    char* FixFileName= malloc(strlen(FileName) + sizeof(EXTENSION_AS));

    sprintf(FixFileName, "%s%s", FileName, EXTENSION_AS);
    return FixFileName;
}
```

do not forget to free the allocated memory when it became useless in your program with `free()`

Comment: You might consider using `strlen(EXTENSION_AS)` instead of `sizeof(EXTENSION_AS)`.  They're both equally fast, since they're both evaluated (in this case) at compile time.  However, `sizeof(EXTENSION_AS)` will count the NUL byte.  In other words, you're allocating an extra byte.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You are right concerning that sizeof count the null charachter. so I will remove the +1 from the expression.

Comment: @DietrichEpp `strlen()` could not executed in the compile time. it's a run time function and it's not a macro

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL, I have a question after seeing your code, sizeof(".as") give results 4, because 3+1(NULL).So I define const char * ws = "hello"; sizeof(ws) gives me 4 on x86 system, why it does not give me 4, not is 6 according you answer?

Comment: @MYMNeo the string `".as"` is defined as a macro in my code and not as a variable. and for your case `ws` is a pointer and the sizeof pointer is 4 for 32-bits systems and 8 for 64-bits systems. you can ask that question and I will try to answer to your question with more details

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Yes, `strlen()` is a function and not a macro, but it **is** evaluated at compile time in circumstances like this.  If you can read assembly, you can verify this for yourself -- be sure to enable optimizations.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It's interesting. I did not know that before. Thank you for the info. In fact I checked and I found that strlen of a literal string is evaluated in the compilation phase. but strlen of a pointer pointing to a literal string is not evaluated in the compilation phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* AddFileExtension(char* FileName)
{
    char* FixFileName=NULL;
    char* Extension = ".as";
    FixFileName=(char *) malloc(strlen(FileName)+strlen(Extension)+1);
    strcpy(FixFileName, FileName);
    strcat(FixFileName, Extension);
    return FixFileName;
}
```

Try the above code. You have to free the memory once you are done

Comment: This has a buffer overrun since it does not allocate memory for a NUL byte at the end.

Comment: Casting the result of malloc is unnecessary and [in some cases harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1600898).